# Binding Angular 2 ng prime slider with range values to input fields

Tags: angular

I'm using ng prime slider. I give range values to the slider and works perfect. For my requirement, I needed 2 input fields where, you can enter the range and the slider moves accordingly. I'm able to achieve this without the "range" option. But I need 2 input fields bound to the slider so that the slider changes its value when input on the text field on min and max.

Code for Without range - This works fine..

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="rangeValues[0]" style="width:190px" />
<p-slider [(ngModel)]="rangeValues[0]" [style]="{'width':'200px'}"></p-slider>
```

Code for with range - Not working..

```
<input type="text" pInputText [(ngModel)]="rangeValues[0]" style="width:190px"/>
<input type="text" pInputText [(ngModel)]="rangeValues[1]" style="width:190px"/>                <p-slider [(ngModel)]="rangeValues" [range]="true [max]="180"orientation="vertical" (onSlideEnd)="slideEnd($event)"(onChange)="handleChange($event)"></p-slider>
```

In ts file enter code here - Range values
    rangeValues: number[] = [1, 180];

An image to clearly imply what I'm saying

[image]

Could you please help?

Comment: Did you manage to fix this? I'm using reactive forms but It looks like the problem is the same:
Let's say I have initial max set to 50;
Then I set it to 40 - everything is fine;
Then i set it to 50 again and right label skyrockets to the moon :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On your input change do something like onInputChange()

```
onInputChange() {
  this.rangeValues = [this.from, this.to];
}

<p-slider class="p-slider-component" [range]="true" [(ngModel)]="rangeValues"></p-slider>
```

Answer (score 0):

For range specify `range` as `true` in property binding. Also keep `rangeValues` array inside `ngModel` instead of having them separate array element in `ngModel`.

```
<p-slider [(ngModel)]="rangeValues" 
   [style]="{'width':'200px'}" 
   [range]="true">
</p-slider>
```

[**Working Example**](https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/blob/master/src/app/showcase/components/slider/sliderdemo.html#L22-L23)

Comment: Range works fine. What I was looking for is that binding input fields to the slider so that when we provide values through input field, the slider moves accordingly. This is happening with non range slider. But with the range specified, its not happening.